# How to deny user type link url of a page website?

Tags: php

I have a page website: http://www.domain.com/test.php
And in that  test.php file i'm using code:

```
<?php
define('ALLOW_ACCESS', 1);
defined('ALLOW_ACCESS') or die("you do not have access to this page");
?>
```

But when i'm accessing this link http://www.domain.com/test.php, the page is still appearing for public. So basically,how do i deny user access of that page .

Comment: I don't think any on really understands your question, could you re-word it.

Answer (score 0):

Erm... How exactly do you expect your code to work? You define a constant, and then if it isn't defined then it denies access. It makes no sense.

Instead, just remove that stuff and leave `die("Access denied");`.

Comment: if i using die("Access denied"); is I can't code on file test.php

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(defined('ALLOW_ACCESS') )...
```

I'm assuming by the all caps, you are trying to define a constant, right?  Otherwise, you'll need to use isset

Answer (score 0):

if you want to deny user access of that page  , then i use this approach . suppose I have config.php file which is not meant for public access just put the below code

```
if(!isset($page-title)
       {header("Location:index.php");
```

Now, on defining public page  just put

```
 $page-title = "I m public page";
```

With this deceleration you can achieve this goal.
*Thanks @dagon, i got this idea from your comment.*